# Grails - Button that calls a controller's method?

Tags: grails

is there a way to call a method from a controller using a button? i did this:

```
<g:form controller="aluno" action="pesquisar"><input type="submit" value="Pesquisar"></g:form>
```

it worked, but, is there another way?

Answer (score 3):

You can use *[actionSubmit](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/actionSubmit.html)* tag:

```
<g:actionSubmit value="My Button" action="myAction" />
```

In a general way, you can use *[createLink](http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Tags/createLink.html)* to generate links to actions:

```
<a href="${createLink(action:'myAction', controller:'myController')}">
```

Comment: i did try to use this, `<g:actionSubmit value="Pesquisar" action="pesquisar" />`, but it does nothing, and the <a> isn't what i'm looking for, i want a button that does it. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to call a method from a button, my method will render the a search page

Comment: Try Ajax calls to a controller in your case.

Comment: @slok did you solve it, I have same issue here, trying with a button to call a controller function and no luck yet

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<g:link class="btn btn-info btn-sm" action="pesquisar" resource="${instance}">TRY IT</g:link>
```

Note : When you click try it Button it will automatically get controller which you currently used.

Comment: it is a link, not a button

Comment: If you want button @rvargas answer is right. I just gave the link that will call your controller action and also it look like button

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, you can use a **button** in place of an **input**:

```
<g:link controller="yourcontroller" action="yourfunction">
    <button type="button">Press me!!!</button>
</g:link>
```